# Complicated Linq expression builder

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I need to build a configurable query builder that allows the user to compound any number of possible conditions.  For example, lets say we have the classic case of `Customer`, `Order`, `OrderItem` and `Product`.  The user wants to be able to draw a report on all orders that have more than 3 items.  Or maybe orders that have exactly one item.  Should be basically the same query, except that the comparator will be different.

The user might also want to tack on a condition that the customer lives in area code 10024.  Or that the order includes at least/most/exactly 2 items of Product ID 14.  Each condition will obviously need to be hard coded in its own method, but the basic signature for each condition will be:

```
private static Expression<Func<Order, bool>> SomePredicate(object someParameters)
```

So far, here's what I've got for the last condition I described:

```
private static Expression<Func<Order, bool>> CountProductItems(int productID, int count, Comparator comparator) {
  Expression<Func<Order, int>> productOrderItems = 
    order => order.Items.Where(i => i.ProductID == productID)
                  .Sum(i => i.Quantity);
  switch (comparator) {
    case Comparator.Equals:
      // return... uh... now what?
    case Comparator.GreaterThan:
      // you get the picture....
  }
}
```

I'm just missing that last syntactical step: how to use that expression `productOrderItems` and return orders where that expression equals/is less than/greater than/etc. the supplied value `count`.

How do you do it?

Comment: Have you considered using Dynamic LINQ?

Comment: `Each condition will obviously need to be hard coded in its own method`.  That's not true.  Using Dynamic LINQ as explained by @ken, you can dynamically filter based on a string containing a column name and a value.  If you store the criteria, you can build up complicated expressions directly and inject them into a `.Where` clause.

Comment: @ken - no I didn't consider it, and I don't really want to if I can help it.  I like strong-typed Linq queries, especially since my organization tends to request schema changes on a scarily regular basis, and I want to see a compiler error if one of my query conditions gets broken.

Comment: @mellamokb - as mentioned in above comment, I'd prefer to avoid using dynamic Linq if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with `Expression` objects inside the method, use `Func`:

```
Func<Order, int> productOrderItems =
    (Order o) => o.Items.Where(i => i.ProductID == productID)
                        .Sum(i => i.Quantity);
```

Then inside your `switch`, you can compose another Lambda expression on top of `productOrderItems` as your return value.  It will automatically be converted to an `Expression`, as `Expression` and `Func` are technically interchangeable:

```
switch (comparator) {
    case Comparator.Equals:
        return (Order o) => productOrderItems(o) == count;
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: +1 Perfect answer, thank you!  (One of these days I need to come to grips with the difference between `Expression` and `Func`)

Answer (score 0):

I've used with success the [Dynamic LINQ Query](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) by ScottGu.

In our case, we need to define in runtime our Where clause, and it worked like a charm.

It's also referred [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/01/14/building-custom-linq-expressions-made-easy-with-dynamicqueryable_2e00_.aspx) with added information.

With this you can do stuff like:

```
var query = Northwind.Products.Where("CategoryID=2 And UnitPrice>3");
```

Comment: Thanks but I went for the strong-typed answer above.   I like strong-typed Linq queries, especially since my organization tends to request schema changes on a scarily regular basis, and I want to see a compiler error if one of my query conditions gets broken.